# How to convert bat commands to java?

Tags: java, batch-file

Is there a way that I can convert bat commands to java. Not saying about an auto converter.

For example, using `echo` in batch what is the equivalent of it in java :)

thank you in advance

Comment: Please ask something more specific, like "how can I print a specific message to the screen in Java, like `echo` in a batch file does?" (if that's what you want to know)

Comment: No you can't. You can call .bat file but there's no specific way to do so.

Comment: Learn batch. Learn Java. Reimplement the batch functionality in Java.

Comment: it is simple, first you need to create batch grammar, use it to parse batch script to geneerate ast, and now you could use it to create java source code or create java byte code and save it as class file so yes there is a way

Comment: I will give you an example. you say " hello " in English, if I translate that to Spanish it will be "ola". That's kinda the concept that I am looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the fast replies. :)

Comment: @user3719086 but do you want to know just that word, or do you want an entire spanish/english dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what is your goal. You can replace `echo` with `System.out.println`.
For calling external commands you can use `ProcessBuilder`:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("command", "param1","param2");
Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

From the `process` you can obtain `InputStream` giving access to console output produced by the process:

```
InputStream processOutput = process.getInputStream();
```

Answer (score 0):

Batches and programs are different.
A *batch* is a sequence of calls to operations available in a system.
A *java program* is a flow of instructions available in the Java API.

In Java `System.out.println` has a result similar to `echo` in a batch.

Comment: +1 A program is more that a batch. Therefore you cant downgrade from java to Bat. But every thing you wrote in bat can be implemented in Java.